# manyshot/ arrowsplit and damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ranged-attack

If a character with a +6 Strength comp. bow uses the talent manyshots and throws 3 arrows at the same time with one attack, does the character add the strength bonus of the bow to each arrow?

If the bow had magical properties like cold damage, would this apply to each arrow? (I am guessing yes to this.)

Does the same apply if the character uses split arrows? (enchant)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> does the character add the strength bonus of the bow to each arrow?

Yes. Manyshot prevents precision damage from applying multiple times, but doesn’t do anything about other damage bonuses. The Strength bonus on damage rolls is not precision damage. (Precision damage is stuff like sneak attack, sudden strike, skirmish, or the duelist’s precise strike.)

> If the bow had magical properties like cold damage, would this apply to each arrow?

Yes, unless that damage is precision damage. The *assassination* property from [this *Cityscape* web enhancement](https://web.archive.org/web/20200401174713/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20070314a) and the *deadly precision* property from *Magic Item Compendium* are the only weapon properties I know of that add or increase precision damage.¹

> Does the same apply if the character uses split arrows? (enchant)

Your question title refers to the conjuration *arrowsplit*, while this mentions “enchant,” which I am *guessing* refers to the *splitting* weapon property found in *Champions of Ruin*.

The answer to both is the same: yes, these copy all features of the split arrow, including the Strength bonus to damage as well as any special weapon properties found on the arrows themselves or imparted upon them by the bow.

1. <sub>Thanks to @Prevarications for finding these two.</sub>

Comment: The *assassination* property from [this Cityscape web enhancement](https://web.archive.org/web/20200401174713/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20070314a) adds precision damage. I believe that an *assassination* weapon with Manyshot is a strange case where having the enchantment on the bow is functionally different from having it on the arrows; on the bow it would only apply once to the volley, but on the arrows each arrow would apply its own bonus—I think. *Deadly precision* from the MIC is probably the same.

Comment: @Prevarications *Deadly precision*, I **think**, counts as increasing your sneak attack and should just be handled the same as any other source of sneak attack. But it’s not clear, and *assassination* is even less clearly that—good call.